# How to save a plot as a black and white png file in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy

I'm trying to save a `matplotlib` plot as a `png` file in black and white to then be able to open the image as a `numpy` array.
The problem is that the `array` I get is made of 4 values for each pixel instead of only 1 (as my image is in B&W)

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# To generate my image
text = 'Text'
plt.text(0.4, 0.4, text)
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig(f'Image.png', dpi=100)
```

Which gives me this image :
[image: The result]

However, when I open it as an `array` with this code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as ima
image = ima.imread(f'Image.png')
print(image)
```

I get something like this :

```
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       ...,

       [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        ...,
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Instead of something like this :

```
array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=float32)
```

I already thought about doing it manually with a `for loop` by creating a new array that
takes the first value of each pixel (made of 4 values) but it might not be optimal...

**Thus, is there a way to do it properly ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

- `plt.save fig()` is saving in RGBA colourspace, i.e. 3 channels of RGB and an alpha/transparency channel hence you get 4 channels
- secondly, PNGs cannot store floats, so you will actually be storing 8 or 16-bit unsigned integers

You can save as PNG as you currently are doing, then read the image as greyscale with **OpenCV** (or **PIL** or other) to just get a single channel in the range 0..255 like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load a single channel greyscale image
na = cv2.imread('Image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(na.shape)     # prints (480,640)
print(im.max())     # prints 255
```

---

If you don't want to introduce **OpenCV**, you could write as `raw` format which is 4 samples (RGBA) per pixel of 8-bit data. That would look like this:

```
...
...your existing code
... 
plt.savefig(f'Image.raw', dpi=100)

# Now read back into Numpy array
na = np.fromfile('Image.raw', dtype=np.uint8).reshape((480,640,4))

# Choose first channel as they should be all the same
im = na[..., 0]
```

---

Note that there is no need to write to disk to save a file and read it - you can write to a memory buffer:

```
from io import BytesIO

# Get a memory buffer
buffer = BytesIO()
# Save as PNG into memory buffer
plt.savefig(buffer, dpi=100)
```

You now have a PNG-encoded image in memory:

```
print(buffer.getvalue()[:20])
```

**Output:**

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\x80'
```